# Travel graph within one level only

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Within a graph there is a group G1 - this group G1 has 3 subgroups S1, S2 and S3. The relation is classified as IS_SUBGROUP_OF.
G1 itsself is again a subgroup of another group, lets call it D1. D1 has a lot of subgroups where G1 is only one.

Having a user U1 who is member of a Subgroup of G1 - here S1. I want to create a query which is able to gather all users of subgroup S1, traverse from user U1 to S1 and from there to G1, get the users of G1 and down from G1 to S2 and S3 and grab all users from S2 and S3 as well. The final result should be all users in the subgroups S1, S2 and S3 from the parent Group G1 including the users of G1.

I have tried:

```
MATCH (d:User) --> (S1:Subgroup)-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..]->(G1:Group) 
WHERE d.name  = "U1" 
RETURN d
```

Unfortunately I traverse all groups and give back all users of any group in the graph. I tried to change the hop-level in the relation (e.g. 1 only) but didnt succeed. Do you have a hint how to create the query to get only this subset of users?

The name of the groups are just for the example and not known in the real world - all I know is the username (here: U1) - and from there I need to find various groups depending where the user is situated. So in the query I cannot work with names of groups but only with variables as they are not known.

*** EDITED ***

Sorry for the confusion, I labeld S1 wrongly as Subgroup, but only the relation mentions 'IS_SUBGROUP_OF', so all Group Nodes have the label 'Group', D1 would also have the label 'Group'. I also add the relation label for users, so the statement looks now like this:

```
MATCH (d:User) -[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-> (S1:Group)-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..]->(G1:Group) 
WHERE d.name  = "U1" 
RETURN d
```

Comment: S1, S2, S3 have the `Subgroup` label, G1 has `Group`, what about D1? And what's the name of the relationship between a (sub)group and a user? Can you update the question with that?

Comment: I corrected and extended the query from my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes the user is identified as a member of a group by the relationship `IS_MEMBER_OF`.

The query first determines the parent group `G1` based on the supplied user `U1`. It then determines all of the users of the child groups of `G1` (S1, S2, S3) and returns the collection of distinct users accross the child groups.

This is a somewhat generalized approach that could be used to traverse more levels by modifying the number of levels to traverse in each situation.

```
// follow IS_MEMBER_OF or IS_SUBGROUP_OF relationships up
// the group/user hierarchy to find the parent group two 
// levels up
match (u:User1 {name: 'U1'})-[:IS_MEMBER_OF|IS_SUBGROUP_OF*2]->(g:Group)

// using the parent group
with g

// follow the IS_MEMBER_OF or IS_SUBGROUP_OF relationships back down 
// the hierarchy to find all of the peer users or the original user    
match (g)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF|IS_SUBGROUP_OF*2]-(u:User)
return collect(distinct u)
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I am trying to wrap my mind around the with-clause as I didnt understand why we would have in the relation between user and group the label 'IS_SUBGROUP_OF'. The feeling is that     match (u:User {name: 'U1'})-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(g:Group)
with g
match (g)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(u:User)
return collect(distinct u)                                                                           gives the same result? Also the query travels up to D1 and gathers users from the next set of subgroups below (lets call it X1 with XS1, XS2, XS3) which was not intended. Struggling :)

Comment: Strange...as far as I can tell, this query should work. It's a bit confusing with the OR matching on relationship labels with degree 2, but it should get the job done...

Comment: I built a test graph and you both are correct, it works as described. Seems in my original graph there is a mistake. So the query is correct - thanks very much!

Comment: Just saw the comments after reloading - perfect, now I got the picture. Thanks for adding the explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this, a minor tweak on Dave's answer (which should work fine, as far as I can tell...)

```
MATCH (:User {name: 'U1'})-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]->(:Group)-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF]->(superGroup:Group)
WITH superGroup
MATCH (superGroup)<-[:IS_SUBGROUP_OF*0..1]-(:Group)<-[:IS_MEMBER_OF]-(users:User)
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT users)
```

Based upon the starting user, this finds the grandparent group or supergroup (G1 according to your example), then matches on users that are members of G1 or any of its immediate subgroups and returns the distinct collection. It will include the original matched user.

Comment: Hi, great, this takes my knowledge a tad further as I know have also a solution how to include the superior group. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
MATCH (d:User)-[*0..1]-(G1:Group)
WHERE d.name= 'U1'
RETURN DISTINCT d
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. I'd assume as long as we query user by name in the where clause we will receive exactly this user no matter how many groups and users are involved.